# Mongodb Aggregate JSON array field for the matching field of other collection

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb , I have two collections like this :

**1st collection name is A**

```
{
"_id": "1234",
"versions": [{

        "owner_id": ObjectId("100000"),
        "versions": 1,
        "type" : "info",
        "items" : ["item1","item3","item7"]


    },
    {

        "owner_id": ObjectId("100001"),
        "versions": 2,
        "type" : "bug",
        "OS": "Ubuntu",
        "Dependencies" : "Trim",
        "items" : ["item1","item7"]

    }
]}
```

**2nd Collection name is B**

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("100000"), "email": "abc@xyz.com" } { "_id": ObjectId("100001"), "email": "bbc@xyz.com"}
```

**Expected output is :**

```
{
"_id": "1234",
"versions":[{

        "owner_id": "abc@xyz.com",
        "versions": 1,
        "type" : "info",
        "items" : ["item1","item3","item7"]


    },
    {

        "owner_id": "bbc@xyz.com",
        "versions": 2,
        "type" : "bug",
        "OS": "Ubuntu",
        "Dependencies" : "Trim",
        "items" : ["item1","item7"]

    }
] }
```

I used mongo $lookup but I am not getting required output 
Please help.

Thank You!!!

Comment: How did you use `$lookup`, can you show us the pipeline?

Comment: I tried with this query

**db.A.aggregate([{
 "$lookup": {
  "from": "B",
  "localField": "versions.owner_id",
  "foreignField": "_id",
  "as": "owner_id"
 }
}, {
 "$unwind": "$owner_id"
}]).pretty()**

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to update your question content with the pipeline, code in comments are discouraged here on SO.

Comment: I have requested to deleted this question and posted with more query info ... Link is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182757/mongodb-aggregate-replace-value-of-one-collection-with-matching-value-of-other)

Comment: No need to delete the question, just use the [edit] link to update the question with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` versions, `$lookup` with another collection on `foreignField`, `$project` to take the first element from the match array, `$group` to get back in original document format

collection a

```
> db.a.find()
{ "_id" : "1234", "versions" : [ { "owner_id" : "100000" }, { "owner_id" : "100001" }, { "owner_id" : "100001" } ] }
```

collection b

```
> db.b.find()
{ "_id" : "100000", "email" : "abc@xyz.com" }
{ "_id" : "100001", "email" : "bbc@xyz.com" }
```

aggregate pipeline

```
> db.a.aggregate(
        [
            {$unwind:"$versions"},
            {$lookup : {from : "b", "localField":"versions.owner_id", "foreignField":"_id", as :"out"}}, 
            {$project : {"_id":1, "versions.owner_id":{$arrayElemAt:["$out.email",0]}}},
            {$group:{_id:"$_id", versions : {$push : "$versions"}}}
        ]   
    ).pretty()
```

output

```
{
        "_id" : "1234",
        "versions" : [
                {
                        "owner_id" : "abc@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                        "owner_id" : "bbc@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                        "owner_id" : "bbc@xyz.com"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: I have deleted this question and posted with more query info ... Link is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182757/mongodb-aggregate-replace-value-of-one-collection-with-matching-value-of-other)

Comment: You don't need to delete, this may be helpful for someone who's looking for a similar issue